# Всплывающая Contact Form из плагина таблицы цен на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Надо при нажатии на кнопку "Заказать" в таблице цен открыть всплывающую форму для заказа.

Установил Contact Form 7, Easy Fancy Box (inline content включил), таблица цен через Pricing Table by Supsystic.

Для кнопки «ЗАКАЗАТЬ» нужно прописать link, каким он должен быть?

Согласно описанию, вызывается таким кодом:

```
<a href="#contact_form_pop" class="fancybox">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
    <div id="contact_form_pop">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[ contact-form-7 id="420" title="ЗАКАЗАТЬ" ]'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Код вставляю в link кнопки в плагине таблицы цен. Дальше в страницу вставляю шорткод таблицы цен. Оно через шорткод не срабатывает. Если сам делаю кнопку, то работает!

И html таблицы цен не могу найти, чтобы пробовать в него вставить.

Answer (score 0):

В link кнопки надо вставлять только `#contact_form_pop`. Код

```
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
    <div id="contact_form_pop">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[ contact-form-7 id="420" title="ЗАКАЗАТЬ" ]'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

должен быть отдельно, один раз в конце страницы. Это так называемая заготовка для попап-окна с формой. Связываются они как раз вот этим идентификатором `#contact_form_pop`.

Код вашей страницы должен выглядеть примерно таким образом:

```
<!-- таблица цен -->
<a href="#contact_form_pop">Товар1 цена1</a>
<a href="#contact_form_pop">Товар2 цена2</a>
......
<a href="#contact_form_pop">ТоварN ценаN</a>

<!-- еще какой-то код -->

<!-- в конце страницы -->
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
    <div id="contact_form_pop">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[ contact-form-7 id="420" title="ЗАКАЗАТЬ" ]'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ДА и так работает! Но я деляю таблицу через плагин Pricing Table by Supsystic и вставляю в страницу только шорткод, если код всплывалки вставить в эту же страницу он не действует, думаю через шорткод не проходит!

Comment: да что вы его в шорткод пихаете, надо вне шорткода заготовку выводить

Comment: Таблица цен делается в плагине, который на выходе выдет шорткод по которому таблица и цепляется к странице. Кода таблицы я невижу поскольку - визуальный конструктор, если би мог видеть код таблицы вставил бы в него код всплывающего окна,  а линк по идентификатору как и советовали, думаю би работало.  А тут понимаю так что #contact_form_pop  невидит кода сплывалки поскольку в разных местах / страницах

Comment: вам этот код и не надо видеть на странице, я описал общую схему, как примерно это должно быть в браузере. Вставьте в конец страницы в визуальном редакторе блок html с кодом заготовки - и все.